# $\operatorname{Res}(V+W)=\operatorname{Res}(V)+\operatorname{Res}(W)$?

Tags: representation-theory, modules

if there are two $R[G]$ Modules $V,W$ and $R$ some ring, $S$ subgroup of $G$. Is the formula $$\operatorname{Res}_S (V \oplus W) = \operatorname{Res}_S (V) \oplus \operatorname{Res}_S (W) $$
true? I know that this works for induction, but haven't found something similar for restriction.

Comment: Yes. V and W are S-submodules of V⊕W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true.  In other words, restriction is an additive functor.  The reason is precisely as in Jack's comment above.